# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host x

Tags: git, ssh, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, gerrit

**Environment:** 
Ubuntu-14.04-LTS
Git Version – 1.9

**Problem:** 
 From the Ubuntu terminal when we run `ssh -Tvvv -p 29418 git-user@gerrit.server.com` it fails with below error.

**Error:**

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gerrit.server.com [101.102.103.104] port 29418.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <Script>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: document.location.href = "https://109.101.11.228:8080/";

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

To fix this problem we have tried the following workarounds, however so far none of them were helped us to fix it.

```
1.  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub key and user name verified in Gerrit GUI Settings.
2.  Permission applied like 
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
3.  Checked /etc/hosts.allow & /etc/hosts.deny files with working machine, both are identical.
4.  Executed unset https_proxy & unset http_proxy commands
5.  Checked .gitconfig file. 
6.  Created vi .ssh/config file and added below info.
Host gerrit.server.com
User git-user
Port 29418
7.  Reinstalled OpenSSL and rebooted the machine.
8.  Tried dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
9.  Firewall not running.
10. Ifconfig shows only eth0 & lo (No problem here).
11. Verified /etc/ssh/sshd_config with working machine, no problem with this file.
```

Comment: Is the user name verified in Gerrit GUI Settings spelled `git-user`?

Comment: yes username is valid. same is registered in our gerrit server.

Comment: `debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: document.location.href = "https://109.101.11.228:8080/";` This is supposed to be an ssh server version string, but instead it looks like some HTML. Your gerrit server isn't listening for SSH on port 29418. Maybe it's been configured for http on that port?

Comment: Our Gerrit server configured to access through 29418 protocol. i am able to do the ssh -Tvvv -p 29418 git-user@gerrit.server.com from another machine, currently problem on one machine.

Comment: Any help you would be highly appreciated.